# Find method in SQL on my PHP page finds everything, even if the record is null

Tags: php, mysql

Ok so I wrote some code to find records on a test database, it works if there is a record and does display the data, if there is no record it still says that it found stuff. It should say it did not. It even finds stuff that is not in the database but obviously has no data to display, its annoying.
I need a new pair of eyes.

I think the error is here:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Kittenzz
        WHERE KittenID='".$_POST['KittenID']."';";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
```

But just in case here is the full code minus the login credentials to the db.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Find'])) 
{
            $connection = mysql_connect("Login Info Deleted");

            // Check connection
            if (!$connection)
        {
            echo "Connection failed: " . mysql_connect_error();
        }
            else
            { //else 1 
                //select a database
                $dbName="Katz";
                $db_selected = mysql_select_db($dbName, $connection); 

                //confirm connection to database
                if (!$db_selected)
                {
                    die ('Can\'t use $dbName : ' . mysql_error());
                }

                else
                { //else 2
            if ($_POST[KittenID]=='')
                    {   
                        $OutputMessage = 'Must add a Kitten-ID';
                    }                       
            else

            {//exception else

                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Kittenzz
                            WHERE KittenID='".$_POST['KittenID']."';";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql, $connection);

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                    $Name = $row['Name'];
                    $KittenID = $row['KittenID'];
                    $KittenAge = $row['KittenAge'];
                    $Email = $row['Email'];
                    $Comments = $row['Comments'];
                    $Gender = $row['Gender'];
                    $Passive = $row['Passive'];
                    $Playful = $row['Playful'];
                    $Activity = $row['Activity']; 

                    }

                if ($result)
                {  
                   $OutputMessage = 'Record Found';
                   //echo "<p>Record found<p>";
                }   
                    else
                    {  
                       $OutputMessage = 'RECORD NOT FOUND';

                    }
                }//exception else
            }//else 2 end

                }//else 1 end


            mysql_close($connection);
}

?>
```

Comment: Just a heads up, mysql is deprecated and should not be used anymore, try Mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: Professor wants mysql, I should really put a warning about that in my questions.

Comment: Professor saying `MySQL` doesnt necessarily mean you have to use PHP's `mysql` extension. You can use php's mysqli or pdo extension to deal with a mysql database just fine. I'm almost certain he meant MySQL database and not forcefully the `mysql_*` api of PHP.

Comment: Holly god. I don't know how to work with mysql anymore. I think  you have to change $sql to $sql = "SELECT * FROM Kittenzz WHERE KittenID=$_POST['KittenID']"; This will be the first step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
      if ($result)
      {  
       $OutputMessage = 'Record Found';
      }
```

There is your mistake, that means if the query executed successfully (even with 0 records) you are saying records found. You should only say that if the number of records returned are more than 0.

```
      if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
      {  
       $OutputMessage = 'Record Found';
      }
```

But the bigger problem with your code can be solved by this reading

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?s=1|8.7936)

Comment: I feel so ashamed everyone tells me this, professor is like, yeah I don't except you guys to solve those issues. That's for next semester...

Comment: Don't be ashamed, just keep going, keep learning keep asking (when your own attempts fail :P ) and keep improving. Forget everything else

Comment: @user3541786 Are you sure you're not being tested by your professor to escape the user input properly?

Comment: @jeroen I could be, but with how little time I got, I will not risk it.

Comment: @user3541786 It's just adding one function call if you are using `mysql_*`.

Answer (score 2):

This may happen, because if `$_POST['KittenID']` is empty, the sql query would look like : `SELECT * FROM Kittenzz WHERE KittenID="";` you have to change the above if statement to:

```
if (!isset($_POST[KittenID]) || empty($_POST[KittenID]) || $_POST[KittenID]=='')
                {   
                    $OutputMessage = 'Must add a Kitten-ID';
                }
```

Comment: You can just use `empty()` and you will have the other 2 conditions automatically as well.